# How do I make a state getter reactive when a dispatched action sets a state object with Vue.set?

Tags: vue.js

I have a button that’s set to update the a store object using Vue.set but the getter for that same piece of data in a different component isn’t reactive until I change the state using a different component method.

1. The state object in question is set up as a hash that's keyed by UUID's. The object is generated and then added to the state object with `Vue.set`
2. The button is set to dispatch an action, which I see it going through immedietely in the devtool, that does this:

```
mutations: {
  COMPLETE_STEP(state, uuid) {
    let chat = state.chatStates[uuid];
    let step = chat.currentStep;

    Vue.set(chat.data[step], "complete", true);
  }
},

actions: {
  completeStep({ commit }, uuid) {
    commit("COMPLETE_STEP", uuid);
  }
},
```

3. Now, when I want to grab that data, I have a getter that grabs that data. This doesn't run until I do something else that causes a re-render:

```
getters: {
  getChatStepComplete: state => (uuid, step) => {
    let chatState = state.chatStates[uuid];

    return chatState.data[step].complete;
  },
}
```

I want the `getter` to show the updated change right away instead of waiting to update on a different re-render. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue: I wasn’t creating the data array when I first create and add chat to the state. Once I started initializing it to an empty array, it’s started being reactive.